# libxml : xpath not found?

Tags: objective-c, xml, xpath, libxml2

I'm completly new to XML, libxml and xpath. Therefore I wanted to parse a very simple XML expression

```
<count>
    <active type="integer">1</active>
</count>
```

I want to retrieve the value 1. I wrote the following code that uses libxml (this code contains objective c code):

```c
const unsigned char* xPathExp = (const unsigned char*) "count/active/text()";
xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression( xPathExp, xpathCtx);
xmlNodeSetPtr nodeSetPtr = xpathObj->nodesetval;
if( nodeSetPtr != 0 ) {
    xmlNode* node = nodeSetPtr->nodeMax > 0 ? nodeSetPtr->nodeTab[0] : 0;
    if( node != 0 ) {
        NSLog(@"Active Projects = %@", [self stringFromCString:node->name] );
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Node for xpath Exp: count/active/text() does not exist.");
    } 
} else
    NSLog(@"nodeSetPtr is null");

xmlFreeDoc(doc);
xmlCleanupParser();
```

It turns out that the output of this code is

```
nodeSetPtr is null
```

So that confuses me. I ran an online xpath evaluator on the xml above and the xpath expression "count/active/text()" return 1.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be as simple as your document setup and what the root element is. first, try `//count/active/text()`. If that works, then try `/count/active/text()`. In general, try not to use `//` unless you really want to match anywhere (great for debugging this particular problem, though). `/count` should find the count element against the root.